# "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 SELECT distinct
   REPLACE(CM_NAME, '/', ' ') as CM_NAME,  
   TO_CHAR(Booking_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS Booking_Date where Booking_Date = 
   '03/20/2018',
   sum(Air_Revenue) as TTL_AIRFARE,
   sum(Room_Revenue) as TTL_ROOM,
   sum(Car_Revenue) AS TTL_CAR,
   sum(Activity_Revenue) as TTL_ACTIVITY,
   0 as TTL_CRUISE
```

so what im trying to do is select yesterdays date but i keep getting this error, what is the most efficient way of doing this with the to_char statement

Comment: You have no `FROM` clause.

Comment: The error seems pretty obvious...

Comment: There is a from clause. I just didn't put it into the statement

Comment: TO_CHAR(Booking_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS Booking_Date where Booking_Date = '03/20/2018' has to be either an inline select, or its where clause has to be following the select list and a from clause.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted doesn't have a `from` clause, but you said you just hadn't included it. It does, however, have a `where` clause - which is in the wrong place. It is also comparing a date with a string, which isn't a good idea as it relies on implicit conversion and session NLS settings. (Perhaps you think it can compare the fixed string with the date you just converted to a string - but that isn't the case, at least in the same level of query, and would be inefficient anyway in this case.) And as you are using aggregate function you need a group-by clause...

It would seem like you want:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CM_NAME, '/', ' ') as CM_NAME,  
   TO_CHAR(Booking_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS Booking_Date,
   sum(Air_Revenue) as TTL_AIRFARE,
   sum(Room_Revenue) as TTL_ROOM,
   sum(Car_Revenue) AS TTL_CAR,
   sum(Activity_Revenue) as TTL_ACTIVITY,
   0 as TTL_CRUISE
FROM your_table
WHERE Booking_Date = DATE '2018-03-20'
GROUP BY REPLACE(CM_NAME, '/', ' '),
   Booking_Date
```

or if you want yesterday's date without having to specify it you can use:

```
WHERE Booking_Date = TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
GROUP BY REPLACE(CM_NAME, '/', ' '),
   Booking_Date
```

That will only match rows where the `Booking_Date` is at exactly midnight. If it actually includes other times then you can do:

```
WHERE Booking_Date >= TRUNC(sysdate - 1)
AND Booking_Date < TRUNC(sysdate)
GROUP BY REPLACE(CM_NAME, '/', ' '),
   TO_CHAR(Booking_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

which will include a single full day of data.