# Missing Expression Error SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle

```
  SELECT distinct
   REPLACE(CM_NAME, '/', ' ') as CM_NAME,  
   TO_CHAR(Booking_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS Booking_Date, 
   where Booking_Date = (sysdate-1),
   sum(Air_Revenue) as TTL_AIRFARE,
   sum(Room_Revenue) as TTL_ROOM,
   sum(Car_Revenue) AS TTL_CAR,
   sum(Activity_Revenue) as TTL_ACTIVITY,
   0 as TTL_CRUISE,
   sum(Air_Revenue + Room_Revenue + Car_Revenue + Activity_Revenue) as 
   TTL_BOOKING
```

so im trying to select yesterdays date using this but i keep getting a missing expression error

Comment: If you are using SQL then why WHERE clause is given in SELECT statement and where is FROM clause and table name

Comment: and if you want yesterdays date, you just have to write this 
`select sysdate - 1 from dual`

Comment: what is "where " doing in the middle of your select?

Comment: Isn't this just a variation on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49412432/266304)? Except now you have added a comma before the `where` clause (still in the wrong place), which has changed the error you get. Please at least try to use [valid syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
REPLACE(CM_NAME, '/', ' ') as CM_NAME,  
TO_CHAR(Booking_Date,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS Booking_Date, 
SUM(Air_Revenue) as TTL_AIRFARE,
SUM(Room_Revenue) as TTL_ROOM,
SUM(Car_Revenue) AS TTL_CAR,
SUM(Activity_Revenue) as TTL_ACTIVITY,
0 as TTL_CRUISE,
SUM(Air_Revenue) +SUM( Room_Revenue) + 
SUM(Car_Revenue) + SUM(Activity_Revenue) as TTL_BOOKING
FROM table_name
WHERE Booking_Date = (sysdate-1)
GROUP BY CM_NAME, BOOKING_DATE
```

I have tried this, replace table_name with your actual table name.